Android studio file creation issues
I am trying to start doing some android studios and have been trying for weeks now but my feeble brain cannot figure out what is wrong or how poorly I'm setting it up. Every time I download it and set it up it doesn't seem to create the files like it does on any video I watch to learn how to use android studio.
These are my files and they are like this for all app types:
enter image description here
These are what all other files are setup as:
enter image description here
Any help is appreciated because I have been stumped and would really love to start coding. Also this example was from the jellyfish version and I have tried the 2024 koala beta version but they both do the same thing.
Didn't know this was a section...

.. And what seems to be the problem? What "files" did you expect to see in the videos? Which files did you get instead?

The files in your screenshot of your Android Studio project look pretty normal. May the video is simply about an older Android Studio version?
